# Android Fragments In A List View

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have looked everywhere for examples on how I can have individual fragments set up as in a list view.   It seems either this is highly not recommended or not possible.  Does anyone have examples that I can look at?  Essentially the app that I am trying to build is a an e-commerce app with a list of items to purchase.  I know it may be overkill to have every item to be listed as a fragment but for this project, I need to do this.

Comment: Why show a fragment for Each Item ? `RecyclerView` should be enough .

Answer (score 1):

This is highly not recommended. If your using a ListView then your xml layout file for each list item will be the same. Ideally if you use a ListView your elements will be mostly the same. You could have one Fragment for when an item is selected from your ListView, however. This one Fragment will be able to function properly for all elements of the ListView. That way you only have on Fragment for all of the elements in your ListView. Having a Fragment for each item in a ListView would be very inefficient.

Comment: Are there any views you recommend? RecycleView? ScrollView?

Comment: RecyclerView is used for a lot of scenarios and I would definitely recommend using one for an ecommerce solution like this. Why? You likely have a dynamic list of items to display and also could need to display a lot of them. RecyclerView will efficiently display these items for you and allow you to scroll through them too if necessary.

Comment: How could I combine RecyclerView with fragments? I am trying to have a scrollable list of fragments

Comment: You should not be trying to have a scrollable list of fragments. There are other solutions. Maybe if you could describe what each item would be in your ecommerce app and why you think you need to use fragments for these we could provide an alternative solution for your implementation.